# Please let me go

Tags: riddle

> I was taken from the ocean,
>   Cast far away.
>   It's time to run,
>   I should be set free.
>   Please let me go, or you'll be sorry.

Who am I?

Edit 1:
To address the question being closed for being too broad, there is a distinct answer that fits all statements when solved. Every line except the first and last contain a direct literal reference to the answer. Next time I will be more clear that the answer should fit literally within the context of words in the inner three lines which will address the concern of over-generality.

Not familiar with the grounds for re-opening so probably won't push for that, will add this edit here for anyone still interested in solving, and will edit the answer in, in a week.

I can release the first clue too which makes the solution more obvious:

> All references should be forgotten.

Comment: It's not sufficient that your intended answer fits all parts of the puzzle. If many answers could fit, then the puzzle is under-specified. A well-crafted puzzle will give enough information to rule in the intended solution while ruling out everything else. Also, potential solutions should be testable by referring to *the puzzle*, not by needing a response from the setter as to whether they're right or not. If the puzzle lacks enough specificity to make that determination, then it's probably *too broad*, and "hints" added to fix that aren't hints, they're a necessary part of the puzzle.

Comment: Also, if you feel the need to provide the solution, please post it as a self-answer. The solution is not part of the question and shouldn't be included in the question post.

Comment: @Rubio question (that is too short to go on meta)? (and thanks for the earlier advice). As this is very old now, do I re-post an improved version, or edit this version now I have a fix for it?

Comment: Usually you want to avoid radically changing a question, as it invalidates answers. In this case, the existing answers were such tenuous attempts anyway that I don’t think it’s necessary to be overly concerned about them, beyond perhaps noting somewhere that a significant revision took place (assuming that’s true). So editing this post to fix it is probably the best thing to do.  I strongly suggest you make all your revisions in a single edit, so when that edit puts this post into the review-for-reopen queue, reviewers will see its fully fixed form.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are:

> Freddie Mercury

Beacause:

*I was taken from the ocean*

> referencing *Seaven seas of Rhye*

*Cast far away*

> referencing *Breakthru*

*It's time to run*

> referencing *Don't stop me now*

*I should be set free*

> referencing *I want to break free*

*Please let me go, or you'll be sorry*

> We all know what happens in *Bohemian Rhapsody*

*KINDA-FUN FACT*

> Another reason why I thought this could have worked is because the songs are in order (from less to most "recent") accordigly to the lines of your poem

Comment: Oh wow! This is really clever and a nice try, but I'd say we must never under any circumstance let Freddy Mercury go :P, may he be remembered forever!

Comment: yeah i knew it was a looooooooong shot ahahah, nice riddle though!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying it, but is it

> a crab?

I was taken from the ocean, Cast far away.

> Crabs come from the ocean.

It's time to run,

> Crabs can move pretty quickly when motivated.

I should be set free. Please let me go, or you'll be sorry.

> Crabs have large pincers that would hurt to be grabbed by.

Comment: Hhaha, unfortunately not the correct answer but amusing none the less. Also, as a side note, it's usually good for your answers if you wrap them in spoiler tags (>!) so it doesn't spoil the surprise for anyone.

Comment: Just add >! before the line you want to add spoilers too. It seems you've gotten it working for the second paragraph so just repeat that :). Make sure there's a space after the !

Comment: It seems like there's no space after the ! in the first and last paragraph

Answer (score 3):

You are

> the **anchor** of an arriving ship.

> I was taken from the ocean,

> When the ship disembarked, you were taken out of the water.

> Cast far away.

> Not only has the ship traveled around with you on it, but also you were *cast* out of metal somewhere on land.

> It's time to run,
>   I should be set free.
>   Please let me go, or you'll be sorry.

> The ship has returned to harbor, and now it is time for you to be released to run freely to the ocean bottom. Failure to release you would allow the ship to drift and be susceptible to damage.

Comment: Nice, I like this, but sadly not the answer I had in mind. I'd say being let go refers to a total disconnection.